# リモートデスクトップの内部エラーが頻発して困っています。

Tags: windows-10

現在、手元のWindows PCから、リモートデスクトップ接続でLAN内のワークステーションに接続しているのですが、下記の内部エラーが頻発する様になり困っています。ワークステーション側のPCにログインするとまた使える様になるのですが、またしばらくすると同じエラーが発生してしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなたか解決策が有ればご教示頂けないでしょうか？

なお、使用しているPCは以下の通りです。
ノートPC:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ワークステーションPC:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 文字で伝えられる情報は、なるべくスクリーンショット(画像)ではなく「文字」として投稿してもらった方が、回答の際の引用や質問を検索する際に親切だと思います。

Comment: @cubick すいません。誤植を防ぐ為に、極力画像を用いていましたが、検索に含まれた方が良いと思われる情報は極力文字にする様にします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

検索するとこんなのが出てきました。これらを参考に調べてみてください。
以下の記事のいくつかにありますが、イベントログを調べるのが早いでしょう。

**サーバ側コンピュータの空きリソースの少なさ**
SessionImageSize値で確保されるメモリ領域の不足
ワークステーションPCのグラフィックスが高機能だと発生しやすい

[リモートデスクトップ「内部エラーが発生しました。」エラーの対処法](https://blog.halpas.com/archives/12327)
[Windowsのリモートデスクトップ接続に失敗する場合の対処方法（RDPDD.dll failed to loadエラーの対処法）：Tech TIPS – ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0904/17/news109.html)
[Win10 Proのリモートデスクトップ接続時の｢内部エラー｣の対処方法／一般的なディスプレイ表示に関わるトラブルの予防措置](https://smcb.jp/diaries/7700278)

**接続速度を確認する**
[リモートデスクトップ接続時に「内部エラーが発生しました。」となる場合の確認点](https://mseeeen.msen.jp/check-point-in-internal-error-when-remote-desktop/)

> リモートデスクトップの接続画面ではいろいろと設定ができます。
>   「エクスペリエンス」タブではパフォーマンスに関する設定ができ、接続速度を選択することが可能です。
>
> 今回はこの接続速度が高速ブロードバンド(2M-10Mbps)になっていることが原因でした。
>   これを低速ブロードバンド(256kbps-2Mbps)に変更することでリモートデスクトップができるようになりました。
>
> 接続環境がころころ変わるよという方は接続品質の自動検出を選んでおくことをおすすめします。
>   しかしながら自動の場合は大概低く検出されるので低速ブロードバンドと変わらないかもしれません。まぁ品質よりも繋がらないことのほうがダメなので当たり前ですが。

**サーバ側コンピュータの電源管理**
ディスプレイ電源OFFとか本体スリープ/サスペンド/ハイバネート状態への移行時間が短いなど。

以下は逆に短時間で復帰してしまう件ですが、調査や設定の方法として。
[Windows10がスリープから勝手に復帰する時に確認すべき項目まとめ](https://deaimobi.com/windows-sleep/)
[Windows10スリープ移行後すぐ起動する。](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/windows10%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97/5a3863f6-3f56-4dda-8e95-42434154aa20)
[Windows10が夜中に勝手にスリープ復帰する場合の解決法](https://freesoft.tvbok.com/win10/tips/sleep_released_unintentionally.html#a02-1)

**その他一般的に**
[リモートデスクトップでの接続で「内部エラーが...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14155254429)

Comment: ありがとうございます。幾つかの情報は私の方ですでに調べて対応したのですが、[Windowsのリモートデスクトップ接続に失敗する場合の対処方法（RDPDD.dll failed to loadエラーの対処法）](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0904/17/news109.html)に関しては未確認でした。上の記事に記載のSessionImageSizeの値を0x40(64Mbytes)にする事で安定してログインできる様になりました。当面様子を見ますが、本件に関してはこれをベストアンサーに採用させてい頂きます！